# MVC Razor View Render in test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, razor, xamarin

I'm trying to figure out a way to inspect a razor view's rendered HTML within a test.

I've been looking at posts where people have asked similar questions, but each time, I fall short. The problem I'm getting is when the view engine tries to load the .cshtml file. It's returning a null reference exception from within the function.

```
[Test]
public void GetRazorViewEngine() {
    var _HttpContextBaseMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
    var _HttpRequestMock = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
    var _HttpResponseMock = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
    _HttpContextBaseMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request).Returns(_HttpRequestMock.Object);
    _HttpContextBaseMock.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(_HttpResponseMock.Object);

    var routeData = new RouteData();
    routeData.Values.Add("controller", "Home");
    routeData.Values.Add("action", "About");

    var controller = new HomeController();
    controller.ControllerContext = new 
    ControllerContext(_HttpContextBaseMock.Object,
                      routeData,
                      controller);
    controller.Url = new UrlHelper(new RequestContext(_HttpContextBaseMock.Object, routeData),
                                   new RouteCollection());


    var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines
                                 .Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(System.Web.Mvc.RazorViewEngine))
                                 .FirstOrDefault();

    var path = "/Users/dan/Projects/Playground/MvcPlayground/Views/Home/About.cshtml";
    var master = "/Users/dan/Projects/Playground/MvcPlayground/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    ViewEngineResult viewEngineResult = razorEngine.FindView(controller.ControllerContext,
                                                             path,
                                                             master,
                                                             false);
}
```

Here is the stack trace of the error.

> at System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache.<.ctor>b__4 (System.String
>   path) <0x3880c90 + 0x00022> in :0  at
>   System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2[TKey,TValue].GetOrAdd
>   (System.Collections.Concurrent.TKey key, System.Func`2 valueFactory)
>   [0x00037] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.4.0-c7sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.4.0-branch-c7sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs:1049
>   at System.Web.WebPages.FileExistenceCache.FileExists (System.String
>   virtualPath) <0x3880880 + 0x0003f> in :0  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerViewEngine.FileExists
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.String
>   virtualPath) <0x38807f8 + 0x0001f> in :0  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPathFromSpecificName
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.String
>   name, System.String cacheKey, System.String[]& searchedLocations)
>   <0x369b9f8 + 0x00039> in :0  at
>   System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.GetPath
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.String[]
>   locations, System.String[] areaLocations, System.String
>   locationsPropertyName, System.String name, System.String
>   controllerName, System.String cacheKeyPrefix, Boolean useCache,
>   System.String[]& searchedLocations) <0x369af00 + 0x0033b> in :0  at System.Web.Mvc.VirtualPathProviderViewEngine.FindView
>   (System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.String
>   viewName, System.String masterName, Boolean useCache) <0x369aa30 +
>   0x000b7> in :0  at
>   MvcPlayground.Tests.HomeControllerTest.GetRazorViewEngine () [0x00163]
>   in
>   /Users/dan/Projects/Playground/MvcPlayground.Tests/Controllers/HomeControllerTest.cs:82
>   at (wrapper managed-to-native)
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&) at
>   System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in
>   /private/tmp/source-mono-4.4.0-c7sr0/bockbuild-mono-4.4.0-branch-c7sr0/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-x86/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:295

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?

Comment: While im not entirely sure if this will help you, you can use global filters in your mvc application to insert login into any part of the MVC pipeline.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Specifically you can use the System.Web.Mvc.ResultExecutedContext.HttpContext.Response to look at the result of your razor rendering.  

In practice I am unsure if this can be used in unit tests.

Comment: Did You resolve the problem? I have similar problem and in my case the problem is that in `HttpContextBase` you have to return some `Cache`, I didt resolve yet how to do it, this doesnt work `_HttpContextBaseMock .Setup(x => x.Cache).Returns(new System.Web.Caching.Cache());` Edit: Damn, 3 years ...

Comment: why are you even trying this? A unit test should not even try to access files on disk

Comment: I am not seeing the .cshtml file being loaded in any where.  I take it that RazorEngine.FindView is supposed to do that?  Or what do you mean when you say "returning a null reference exception"?  I'm assuming you mean that a null reference exception was thrown within the given function, but perhaps you mean that the function set a particular value to null, causing the exception to be thrown later.  A void cannot literally return a null reference exception.

Answer (score 1):

Look at ([Razor engine cant find view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43996438/razor-engine-cant-find-view))
also note that RazorViewEngine's had some problems with pre-compiled views in the past:
https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6672.  However, It looks to me like RazorViewEngine has changed a little bit within the past 5 years.  I'd say it is time to update and try again.

Comment: Edit: I have no idea if your view is precompiled or not.